# base link and search api

Tags: javascript, jquery, radix

I am attempting to query a database through an API which I don't fully understand. I have been sent an example of the API being used with a keyword search form. The form is an html file and uses jquery return JSON documents, format items into an array array, and display.

I tried to build the design of my application and manipulate the form to work within my pages. The file the uses the API requires that the a base link be used.

```
<base href="{{app_root}}">
```

If I remove this base link my functionality of the search is lost. If I use the base link all of presentation and CSS is lost.

I thought maybe I could change the base link dynamically when I needed to call the search file with:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function setbasehref(basehref) { 
     var thebase = document.getElementsByTagName("base"); 
     thebase[0].href = basehref; 
} 
//setbasehref("{{app_root}}");
setbasehref("{{app_root}}");
</script>
```

Then use setbasehref() to change it back to my original base link, but that didn't work.

I'm new to javascript and JSON, and I'm not entirely sure what app_root is doing. Any thoughts?

Comment: look in source view to see what it genrates, look in browser console net/network tab to see what paths your css are trying to find. Adjust app_root to full domain path if it helps

Comment: I forgot to include that that the base link needs to be {{app_root}}/. I omitted the slash in my original post. I looked at the source in two pages: one that uses {{app_root}}/ base and one that does not. I am using the full domain path for both css files.

Comment: so assume you resolved issue..great

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter before I finished the post. Here is the rest: When I look at how the path is being used it looks the same. There is no css applied to my page with app_root base.  The path to my links change also with app_root. For example: instead of being /home/browse/page.php it becomes /home/{{app_root}}/browse/page.php

Comment: not sure whay a json file would need your base tag to start with. Without seeing live page there are too many unknowns